# regex not returning 2 separate matches as it should

Tags: python, regex

Trying to capture both sentences as separate groups. The regex currently only captures the first sentence only.

string =

*Mazda67 vehicle J8473 operated with R/H Nose tire missing Tang Washer
following replacement of wheel assembly by dealership maintenance
personnel.During an inspection at Ford, maintenance personnel found
the tang washer missing and replaced R/H engine mount.*

regex =

```
(?:^|\.|;)([^.]*missing.*?)(?:\.|$)
```

Currently returns this only:

Mazda67 vehicle J8473 operated with R/H Nose tire missing Tang Washer
following replacement of wheel assembly by dealership maintenance
personnel.

Desired output:

Match 1:

Mazda67 vehicle J8473 operated with R/H Nose tire missing Tang Washer
following replacement of wheel assembly by dealership maintenance
personnel.

Match2:

During an inspection at Ford, maintenance personnel found the tang
washer missing and replaced R/H engine mount.

I'm using the regex tester here to test:  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please show us the actual code.  (i.e. maybe it's because you're calling `.match()` instead of `.search()`?  We need to see the exact code, so we know exactly what you're doing...)

Comment: I'm using the regex tester site  John. No match or search is used there.

Comment: Try `(?:^|(?<=[.;]))([^.]*missing.*?)(?:\.|$)` https://regex101.com/r/n6xaiw/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching, you can use a lookbehind assertion to not consume the last dot at the end of the string in the first match, that you also want to match in the beginning of the second string.

```
(?:(?<=[;.])|(?<=^))[^.]*missing[^.]*(?:\.|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:(?<=[;.])|(?<=^))` Assert either `;` or `.` or the start of the string
- `[^.]*missing[^.]*` Match `missing` between optional chars other than a dot
- `(?:\.|$)` Match either `.` or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DRjnQM/1)

Note that there is a shorter way of writing the alternation in the comments by @[sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15577665/sln), just using `^` instead of `(?<=^)` as the anchor also does not match a character.

Comment: Thanks The fourth. Why is my method not working?

Comment: @ImNotLost Because you are matching the dot at the end of the first match, and you can not consume the character again for the start of the second match. In that case, you can assert the characters (non consuming) instead.

Comment: and the non-consuming method is using lookbehind/lookahead?

Comment: @ImNotLost That is correct, I will explain the parts of the pattern, 1 moment..

Comment: Pity that python re doesn't like `(?<=^|[;.])[^.]*missing[^.]*(?:\.|$)`

Comment: @anubhava would it make a difference ?